# Remove Carriage Return & New Line from XML file with Powershell Script

Tags: xml, powershell

Need your help to remove Carriage return (`r) & new line character (`n) from my XML file. I'm getting *System.OutOfMemoryException* error

The size of File :600 MB

Number of Lines: 1

Input File Format

```
<File1>
 <SubFile1> </SubFile1>
 <SubFile2> </SubFile2>
 <SubFile3> </SubFile3>
 .........
 <SubFilen> </SubFilen>
</File1>
```

Code used

```
$content = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($input_File)
$content = $content.Replace("`r","")
$content = $content.Replace("`n","")
[system.io.file]::WriteAllText($Output_File,$content)
```

Also tried

```
Get-Content
```

I tried with MaxMemoryPerShellMB **1024, 2048, 4096** but no luck.

Comment: `(Get-Content .\file.xml)-join''`

Comment: I'm not getting any error if I execute it from Powershell prompt.                                    `C:\Temp\File_Encoding.ps1 "input.xml" "output.xml"`                                          I'm getting error when I try to execute like below                                                      `C:\Windows\syswow64\Windowspowershell\v1.0\Powershell.exe -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -File "C:\Temp\Change_File_Encoding.ps1" "input.xml" "output.xml"`

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice article from Don Jones [Why Get-Content Ain’t Yer Friend](http://powershell.org/wp/2013/10/21/why-get-content-aint-yer-friend/).

Try to use a  `StreamReader` to read the file line by line and use a `StreamWriter`to write a new (temp) file line by line. After you are finish, just replace the files:

```
$streamReader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader -Arg "yourFile.xml"
$streamWriter = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "tmp.xml"

while ($line = $streamReader.ReadLine()) {
  $replacedLine = $line -replace '`r|`n'
  $streamWriter.Write($replacedLine);
}

$streamReader.close()
$streamWriter.close()

Remove-Item "yourFile.xml" -Force
Rename-Item "tmp.xml" "yourFile.xml"
```

Comment: WriteLine() introduces another newline, defeating the purpose

Comment: Of course, thanks for the hint. He have to use `Write` instead - fixed my answer.

Comment: Still I'm getting the same error.                                                                 `ERROR encountered - Control has passed to Catch Block
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
Error occurred at line 56`